# Is there an option or hint possible to improve performance of query with multiple values in the "in" clause

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan, execution

We have a table CustomerNote with 4 columns ID, CustomerID, Note, Date

There is an index on CustomerID asc, Date desc

When the following query is executed

```
select top 30 
    Date 
from CustomerNote
where CustomerID in (1,5)
order by Date desc
```

The index is used, but it's still fetching ALL CustomerNotes for the customerID's 1 & 5, to then sort/top, causing a lot of CPU usage.
[image]

This is due to the multiple values in the "in" clause. I know that the "in" clause will never have more values than 10, so it would be a much better approach if sql server iterates over the 10, fetches at least 30 per customerID and the merge, sorts & tops. Is there a query hint or option to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like it might be better if you join a Table Valued Parameter, temp table or `VALUES` clause. This means that each `CustomerID` will be queried individually in a correlated `APPLY` then sorted.

```sql
select top (30) 
  cn.Date 
from (values
    (1),
    (5)
) v(CustomerID)
cross apply (
    select top (30) cn.*
    from CustomerNote cn
    where v.CustomerID = cn.CustomerID
    order by
      cn.Date desc
) cn
order by
  cn.Date desc;
```

Answer (score 9):

You're probably better off writing the transformation you want manually, but in the spirit of finding something the optimizer can just about do for you with minimal changes:

```
SELECT TOP (30) 
    CN.[Date] 
FROM dbo.CustomerNote AS CN
WHERE 
    CN.CustomerID IN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 5)
ORDER BY 
    CN.[Date] DESC;
```

[image: Plan]

Yes, it would be nice if the optimizer explored this sort of option for you without changing syntax.

#### Example table and data

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerNote
(
    CustomerID integer NOT NULL,
    [Date] datetime NOT NULL
);
```

```
WITH 
    N (n) AS
    (
        SELECT 
            SV.number 
        FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS SV
        WHERE
            SV.[type] = N'P'
            AND SV.number >= 1
    )
INSERT dbo.CustomerNote
    WITH (TABLOCKX)
(
    CustomerID, 
    [Date]
)
SELECT 
    C.n, 
    DATEADD
    (
        MINUTE, 
        -D.n * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 1000,
        GETDATE()
    )
FROM N AS C
CROSS JOIN N AS D
WHERE
    C.n BETWEEN 1 AND 9;

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX 
    [IX dbo.CustomerNote CustomerID, Date-] 
ON dbo.CustomerNote
    (CustomerID, [Date] DESC);
```

That loads 2047 randomish date values for ten different customers:

```
SELECT CN.CustomerID, NumRows = COUNT_BIG(*) 
FROM dbo.CustomerNote AS CN
GROUP BY CN.CustomerID
ORDER BY CN.CustomerID;
```

| CustomerID | NumRows |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2047 |
| 2 | 2047 |
| 3 | 2047 |
| 4 | 2047 |
| 5 | 2047 |
| 6 | 2047 |
| 7 | 2047 |
| 8 | 2047 |
| 9 | 2047 |

Running the solution code produces a post-execution plan where **14 rows** are read from an ordered index seek for customer 1 and **17 rows** from a similar seek for customer 5:

[image: actual plan]

[*db<>fiddle* demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/T0j6y9Zg)

The plan does **not** read all 2047 rows for each customer.

Note also this solution does not require a sort operator.

---

The solution is quite general, though there are some [sorting conditions](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/09/t-sql-queries/avoiding-sorts-merge-join-concatenation) to meet for the *Merge Concatenation*.

If you want to project a different column, that column would need to be part of the index key (not as an include) to meet the sorting requirement; or you could fetch only a key for the table and look up the extra column(s) as a separate step after finding the required small number of keys.

Additional demos with an extra column:

- https://dbfiddle.uk/nNKi4m0P (added to index key)
- https://dbfiddle.uk/D4fNdMf2 (key plus lookup)

Answer (score -4):

The `top` and `order by` are always applied last. You cannot expect optimizer to do pre-filtering of rows based on `order by` clause.

But you can reduce number of records for sorting, by using something like

```
select top 30 
    Date 
from CustomerNote
where CustomerID in (1,5) and Date>datadd(day, -60, getdate())
order by Date desc
```

So assuming you have 30+ records in the last sixty days, you will get these records, sort them, and throw out extra.
The actual number of days, you would have to guess, based on your data.